# JavaScript: возможен ли запуск скрипта в одну строку при событиях onload и onresize?

Tags: javascript

Этот код запускает функцию `func()` как при загрузке страницы, так и при изменении ширины окна:

```
  window.onload = function() {
        window.onresize = func;
        func();
    };
```

Можно ли написать это более компактно (в одну строку, и, разумеется, меньшим количеством символов)?

Answer (score 2):

Можно так, но это "плохая практика"

```
onload = onresize = function(e) {};
```

Правильнее использовать метод `addEventListener()`

См. также:

1. [Введение в браузерные события](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#addeventlistener-%D0%B8-removeeventlistener)

Comment: Почему плохая? Какие могут быть ошибки?

Comment: @VostokSisters Таким образом задается один обработчик. Если до этого момента был задан другой обработчик - он не будет работать по событию. `addEventListener()` добавляет обработчик в список. При наступлении события будут вызваны все обработчики по очереди (если только кто-то из них не вызовет `stopImmediatePropagation()`). Подробности почитайте в прикрепленной ссылке